# Knockout Cascading Dropdowns with exising id value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 2 dropdowns populated from observable arrays. The second one is filtered by the first result. This works fine. Even though the value of the id of the second one is set before binding, binding seems to wipe it and won't change it again.

I also do not understand why it won't display json of the viewModel.

html

```
 <p>
     <label>Serial Number</label>
     <span data-bind="text: PartNumber"></span>
     <span data-bind="text: Revision"></span>
     <span data-bind="text: SequenceNumber"></span>
</p>      

<label>Description</label>        
<input data-bind="value: Description" />

<label>Usage</label>
<select data-bind="options: UsageTypes, optionsText: 'UsedType', optionsValue: 'UsedTypeID', value: UsedTypeID"></select>
<select data-bind="options: UsageFiltered, optionsText: 'UsedOn', optionsValue: 'UsedOnID', optionsCaption: 'select...', value: UsedOnID, visible:UsedTypeID"></select>

<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(viewModel)"></p>
```

javascript

```
var data = {"PartNumber":"SAMPLE123456","Revision":"D","SequenceNumber":"1","SerialNumber":"SAMPLE123456D001","Description":"This is a test","SupplierID":"4","UsedTypeID":"U","UsedOnID":0} ;

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

viewModel.UsageTypes = ko.observableArray( [{"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product"},{"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series"},{"UsedTypeID":"U","UsedType":"Unknown"}]);
viewModel.UsagesList = ko.observableArray(
[{"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product","UsedonID":14,"UsedOn":"banana"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product","UsedonID":16,"UsedOn":"kjhkjhkj"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product","UsedonID":7,"UsedOn":"prod1234"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product","UsedonID":15,"UsedOn":"things"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"P","UsedType":"Product","UsedonID":20,"UsedOn":"thinkgs2"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":17,"UsedOn":";lkgd;ldf"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":18,"UsedOn":"df;lkjdflk"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":13,"UsedOn":"fdsdfsdf"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":12,"UsedOn":"mn,m,m,"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":19,"UsedOn":"rubberchicken"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"S","UsedType":"Series","UsedonID":11,"UsedOn":"sdfsdfsdf"},
 {"UsedTypeID":"U","UsedType":"Unknown","UsedonID":0,"UsedOn":"Unknown"}]);

viewModel.UsageFiltered = ko.computed(function(){
    var filter = this.UsedTypeID();
    if (!filter){
        return this.UsagesList();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.UsagesList(), function(item) {
            return filter === item.UsedTypeID    
        }); 
    }
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimconstable/5rg6e/)

Answer (score 0):

I added a computed method that returns the JSON and bound that to the HTML of the paragraph tag and it worked.

```
<p data-bind="html: jsonText"></p>


viewModel.jsonText = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.toJSON(viewModel);
}, viewModel);
```

Updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5rg6e/5/

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why it didn't work the other way??? and there is still the binding issue.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work, but I suspect that the ko.JSON() isn't observable so you can't bind to it.  Plus, its not on the view model.